# How enableProdMode() and optimization=true works together in Angular

Tags: angular, angular14

I am working on an Angular-14 application, on which I have removed **enableProdMode()** function call from **main.ts**.

We have removed it because documentation says- **Using this method is discouraged as the Angular CLI will set production mode when using the optimization option.** In my **angular.json**, **optimzation** flag is enabled.

But the issue after removing the function call is, even though my angular.json has optimzation flag true and I am building my application by **--configuration production** then also **isDevMode()** method is returning true in main.ts.

The requirement is I have to do some stuffs in prod/dev mode and the check on main.ts looks like below-

```
if(environment.production && isDevMode()) {
   // code block 1 
} else{
  // code block 2
}
```

control always go to code block 1. It's never going inside code block 2.